# Detect Telosb emission using USRP Source

Tags: zigbee, usrp

I am using N210 USRP to have a RF spectrum around 2.4GHz range.
I have programmed two TelosB nodes and they are using RadioCoundLed to send and Receive signals
I have set the TelosB nodes at highest power level following the datasheet
I also made them fixed at a channel(26) around 2.48Ghz
I can see the Telosb nodes communication and the LEDS are blinking.

Now I should observe this in USRP RF spectrum. However I am observing nothing in Scope Sink. I have fixed the center freq in the 2.48 Ghz range.
Set the RX gain - 0
Sampling rate is 2M

Is it possible to even to observe it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the problem. I was using the wrong daughter board. Now I am using the SBX board that can support 2.5Ghz range.